# React-Bootstrap No me carga los estilos

Tags: reactjs

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]les explico mi problema:
estoy visualizando en el navegador una tarjeta de Bootstrap y me aparece sin los estilos. les dejo el código del archivo app.jsx y el del archivo CardComponet.jsx. Ademas una foto de como estoy viendo la tarjeta sin estilo.

No logro ver donde esta el error.

app.jsx

```
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import CardComponent from "./component/CardComponent";

const App = () => {
return (
  <div className="App container">
    <div className="row">
      <CardComponent />
    </div>
  </div>
);
};
```

export default App;

CardComponet.jsx

```
const CardComponent = () => {
return (
  <div class="card col-4">
    <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="..." />
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">
        Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the
        bulk of the card's content.
      </p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">
        Go somewhere
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

};
export default CardComponent;

Answer (score 0):

Has añadido el cdn de bootstrap al head del html de tu aplicacion? Este es el de la version 5.2, si no es la tuya, busca el correspondiente en la web

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
```

Comment: Suso gracias era ese el problema.